# When did the concepts colloquially referred to as "the past" and "the future" first appear?

Tags: time

I'm writing a paper on the history and the origin of Time and I'm finding it impossible to locate any meaningful material on how the concepts colloquially referred to as "the past" and "the future" originated and then were transmuted from being a category sets of events - to places that now exist elsewhere.

For example, the set of all events that occurred before some moment in time were categorized as "the past", and the set of events that will occur after some moment in time were categorized as "the future".

Thus the past and future are an abstract collection of events. However, how and when did that change and humanity started thinking of "the past" and "the future" as being places that we physically travel from and to at a rate of one second per second?

No pun intended, but what are the histories of "the past" and "the future" as concepts and how did they evolve?

Comment: These concepts predate written history - humans must have developed an intuition for the past and future before the historical record.  After all, we remember the past and we plan the future.  As an specific example from extant western philosophy, Aristotle talks of a future sea battle in his argument for [fatalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatalism).  Prior to Aristotle, Parmenides argued that change is impossible and time is an illusion, thus denying a past and a future.  In fact, the presocratics were largely obsessed with change and time - being and becoming.